# Courier-base fails to install on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS base install

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4.

I just did a base install on Sunday where everything worked fine.  I am using Ansible to ensure my installs are all identical.  As of July 10, 2018, when I tried add `courier-base` to the base install it fails with the following error:

```
Setting up courier-base (0.68.2-1ubuntu7) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package courier-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 courier-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I looked in the `/etc/alternatives` and I did not seem to find any `courier-base` entries.  If I touch the missing file, it just continues with a long list of missing `man` files.  What could have happened in 1 day? Should I submit a bug report on this?

Comment: By touching the following files, I get courier-base to install, but it seem hackish.  I am assuming they were not added or were removed from the install package. touch /usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz
touch /usr/share/man/man8/deliverquota.courier.8.gz
touch /usr/share/man/man1/maildirmake.courier.1.gz
touch /usr/share/man/man7/maildirquota.courier.7.gz
touch /usr/share/man/man1/makedat.courier.1.gz

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change that added the answer but you can always review a post’s history through the link below it.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz` ought to be [part of the package `courier-base`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/courier-base/filelist) but Apt claims that the file is missing during package *configuration*. I suspect the following course of events:

1. Something instructed DPKG to install `courier-base` but the package configuration failed for some reason and left the package in a half-installed state.
2. Something removed the file `/usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz` but not its “owner” the package `courier-base`.
3. Apt tries to configure half-installed packages but fails due to the missing `/usr/share/man/man5/maildir.courier.5.gz` that is required for the package's post-installation step.

You should be able to solve the issue with a *complete re-installation* of the affected package:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall courier-base
```

This will also overwrite the hackish work-around that you describe in your comment.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!